# Maya 2015 Suggestions for speeding up exporting when scene has animation

Tags: animation, export, maya

I am able to export per frame object data from Maya 2015 using a custom File Translator.

When I export animation from a scene my exporter moves the time slider along each frame and writes out the new values (such as position) for the channels that are animated. This repeats for all animated channels until we reach the last animation frame.

Exporting this way causes Maya's viewport to update each frame. During export I don't really want/need this to happen.

Does anyone know of any way to update all logical data per frame in Maya without requesting the viewport also reflects these updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off viewport is one option but using refresh is 10 times faster.

```
cmds.refresh(suspend=True)
doYourFunc()
cmds.refresh(suspend=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra input on this, I'll give this a try and if it turns out to work faster than @DrHaze suggestion I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key function you are looking for to turn the viewport off is:

```
from maya import mel
mel.eval("paneLayout -e -manage false $gMainPane")
```

And to turn it on:

`mel.eval("paneLayout -e -manage true $gMainPane")`

Where `$gMainPane` is a mel global variable containing the path of your viewport.

---

From [Asimation Blog](http://blog.asimation.com/disable-maya-viewport-while-running-code/):

> When running a process that loops through the scene frames, like bake
>   animation or export geo, Maya will update the viewport per frame. This
>   update is redundant and will slow the process down. So to avoid that,
>   we can turn off the viewport while the code is running.

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Imports
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
from functools import wraps
from maya import cmds
from maya import mel


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Decorators 
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def viewportOff( func ):
    """
    Decorator - turn off Maya display while func is running.
    if func will fail, the error will be raised after.
    """
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap( *args, **kwargs ):

        # Turn $gMainPane Off:
        mel.eval("paneLayout -e -manage false $gMainPane")

        # Decorator will try/except running the function. 
        # But it will always turn on the viewport at the end.
        # In case the function failed, it will prevent leaving maya viewport off.
        try:
            return func( *args, **kwargs )
        except Exception:
            raise # will raise original error
        finally:
            mel.eval("paneLayout -e -manage true $gMainPane")

    return wrap

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Export/Bake function
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
@viewportOff
def export():
    """
    the export/bake process
    """
    # do something
    print "running some process"
    for i in range(1000):
        print i


export()
```